# apache rewrite not routing unicode urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, utf-8

I am using Xampp [Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.5.38].

When I route through alias domain names like domain.dev (set in windows host to redirect to 127.0.0.1) everything is working as expected (urls like `domain.dev/سایت` are routing correctly) but when I use `localhost/site_root/سایت` I get 404 not found error.

All the non unicode/utf8 urls are routed correctly; for instance `localhost/site_root/path1/path2`.

I have already commented line `Alias /error/ "D:/xampp/apache/error/"` in *apache/conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf* as commenting this allowed domain access possible.

Here are related config/files:

**host:**

`127.0.0.1 domain.dev`

**apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/site_root"
    ServerName domain.dev
    ServerAlias demo.domain.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

**htdocs/site_root/.htaccess:**

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
IndexOptions +Charset=UTF-8
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```